# Determine the Kernel and Homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that $\phi$ is a homomorphism from $S_{4}$ onto $Z_{2}$. Determine Ker $\phi$. Determine all homomorphisms from $S_{4}$ to $Z_{2}$.

What I have so far: We know by the First Isomorphism Theorem that |$S_{4}$|/ |Ker $\phi$| =| $Z_{2}$|. So $24$/ |Ker $\phi$|= $2$. Hence, |Ker $\phi$| =$12$. Not sure what else to do after this.

Comment: What is denoted by $Z_2$ in this context?

Comment: The set of integers modulo 2.

Comment: Seen as $\{-1,1\}$, I suppose?

Comment: Just $\{$ $0$,$1$$\}$ I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already deduced that the order of the group must be $12$. Try to prove that $A_n$ is the only subgroup of index $2$ in $S_n$ and you are done, because the kernel must be exactly $A_n$. This tells us that the image of an element in $A_n$ is $0$ and the image of every other element is $1$(Since the only options are $0$ and $1$ and we know the kernel is $A_4$), this determines the homomorphism uniquely.

Comment: What do you mean by $A_n$ is the only subgroup of index 2 in $S_n$. don't we need $n<5$?

Comment: No, gary. For every n , $A_n$ is the only subgroup of index $2$ in $S_n$.